# How "$!" text will be returned in UTF-8 in Perl?

Tags: perl

I read the Perl document about ["$!" text will be returned in UTF-8 when appropriate](https://perldoc.perl.org/perl5220delta#%22$!%22-text-will-be-returned-in-UTF-8-when-appropriate)

> The stringification of $! and $^E will have the UTF-8 flag set when the text is actually non- ASCII UTF-8. This will enable programs that are set up to be locale-aware to properly output messages in the user's native language. Code that needs to continue the 5.20 and earlier behavior can do the stringification within the scopes of both use bytes and use locale ":messages". Within these two scopes, no other Perl operations will be affected by locale; only $! and $^E stringification. The bytes pragma causes the UTF-8 flag to not be set, just as in previous Perl releases.

Could you give me an example? Thank for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This means that `$!` will contain Unicode Code Points rather than encoded text since 5.22.

For example, the message associated with `errno` `1` is `Opération non permise` in this system's French locale, which contains non-ASCII character U+E9 LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE ("é").

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_CA.UTF-8 5.20t/bin/perl -E'use locale; say sprintf "%vX", $!=1'
4F.70.C3.A9.72.61.74.69.6F.6E.20.6E.6F.6E.20.70.65.72.6D.69.73.65
      ^^^^^
      U+E9 encoded using UTF-8

$ LC_ALL=fr_CA.UTF-8 5.22t/bin/perl -E'use locale; say sprintf "%vX", $!=1'
4F.70.E9.72.61.74.69.6F.6E.20.6E.6F.6E.20.70.65.72.6D.69.73.65
      ^^
      U+E9 as Unicode Code Point
```

As such, messages will output properly when you add an encoding layer to the output.

```
$ LC_ALL=fr_CA.UTF-8 5.20t/bin/perl -we'use open ":std", ":locale"; use locale; die($!=1);'
OpÃ©ration non permise at -e line 1.

$ LC_ALL=fr_CA.UTF-8 5.22t/bin/perl -we'use open ":std", ":locale"; use locale; die($!=1);'
Opération non permise at -e line 1.
```

Comment: @ikegami The OP will have to install that locale, otherwise perl will complain about `Setting locale failed', etc. Also, your examples assume a Unix machine, and a bourne-like shell.

Comment: They don't have to do anything of the kind. They don't have to run the commands I posted at all. I conveniently posted their output.